# How to work with ENUM types in sql with java

Tags: java, mysql, enums

Hello I have one field for STATUS in the database as a enum type.

But how do I create the setters for this? as String, INT or the "Java Enum"

something like this

```
public enum getStatus() {
    return Status;
}

public void setStatus(enum Status) {
    this.Status = Status;
}
```

Comment: How are you accessing the database? Are you using JPA? Does your database support enum-type columns like PostgreSQL does?

Comment: The setters of what? If it's an enum in database, it's probably a good idea to also have an enum in your Java code.

Comment: see I have added code example above.. is that a good way to do this?

Comment: Respect the Java naming conventions. Variables start with a lowercase letter. And read the tutorial about enums, since you don't know how they work. You would find it by googling for "Java tutorial enum" and clicking on the very first link. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the name of the enum as the type for `status`. Some like this

```
enum MyEnum { // Assuming MyEnum is the name of the enum
    // enum values sample below
    ACTIVE, INACTIVE, PENDING
}
```

*Edit:* After our discussion, this might suit you more.

```
private MyEnum status;

public String getStatus() {
    return this.status.name();
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = MyEnum.valueOf(status);
}
```

Comment: Can u modify ur answer with the enum values included?

Comment: How would I know the values of the enum you're using?! You would know it better than anybody else.

Comment: I meant like how do I declare the different status?

Comment: Okay. In that case, check the edited answer now. I've added a few sample values.

Comment: I changed my code like this but in the getter and setter after this.status  it says im missing an expression?

Comment: I used `status` instead of `Status` out of habit. May be the case is the problem.

Comment: Do I also have to declare private MyEnum status?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40422/discussion-between-r-j-and-reshad)

Comment: @Reshad: some things have to be learnt before being used. Enums are part of them. Read the Java tutorial about enums.

Answer (score 1):

I would see if this suited you:

```
public enum MyStatus { ACTIVE, INACTIVE, PENDING }

public class OtherClass
{
  private MyStatus status = null;

  /* other code */

  /* when it is time to get a value of status to store in the database: */
  String statusString = status.name();

  /* when it is time to take a string from the database 
   * and translate to the variable */
  status = MyStatus.value(stringFromDatabase);

}
```

You do have to remember that you cannot eliminate values from the enum in a later version of the program, or you have to remember to eliminate all of them from the database, or you have to catch the resulting exception from valueOf() and do something intelligent with it.

Comment: Im going to add the values retrieved from the database in a JComboBox